# HTML table cell spacing - only between cells, no outer one

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add cell spacing to a html table.

I want to add spacing between cells without the outer spacing.

My problem is, that the `cellspacing` html attribute and `border-spacing` CSS property adds spacing outside too.

[image: cellspacing image]

I would like to put cell spacing without the red (outer) part - only the yellow one.

Is it possible?

#### Edit:

1. The image was drawn by hand (MS-Paint) only for illustration.
2. The coloring is for debugging - so that one can see where the borders, and spacing is.

I have found a roundabout solution including some additional `div`-s:

```css
.inner-spacing {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.inner-spacing td {
  padding: 0;
}
.inner-spacing td > div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.inner-spacing tr:first-child > td > div {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.inner-spacing tr:last-child > td > div {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.inner-spacing tr > td:first-child > div {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.inner-spacing tr > td:last-child > div {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="inner-spacing">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**So to summarize, I would like the table to have border spacing with the table border collapsing onto the cells (no spacing).**

I wonder if there are some other solutions - so any new solution is welcome!

Comment: Can you post your html/css?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think is needed it otherwise I have to smell my fingers :)

Comment: @AlexChar That's the max I can get it. Check my answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You have my vote ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be tricky a little bit...you will need to set `display:block` and `border-spacing:10px` for spacing between cells and same negative `margin:-10px` to remove the outer spacing

***Stack Snippet***

```css
table {
  font: bold 13px Verdana;
  background: black;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

table tbody {
  margin: -10px;
  display: block;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is kinda tricky, you need to follow something like this:

```css
table, td {border: 1px solid #999; border-collapse: collapse;}
table {margin: -5px;}
table td {width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 5px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @AlexChar I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: I mean the first version before the edit. Is more accurate.

Comment: @AlexChar nopes. That doesn't actually answer the question. `:)`

Comment: Then OP have to decide ;)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think your new version answers the question either. The OP says _I would like to put cell spacing without the red (outer) part - only the yellow one._, but there appears to be no spacing at all in your table (so no yellow part).

Comment: @HiddenHobbes is right. The first version had the red and the yellow part, and the secont does not have either. I updated the question, and added a runnable snippet witch 'sorta' solves the problem - I hope this clarifies the question.